# ICS upgrade to Thunderbolt deleted my Family Contact Group from Home Screen

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, home-screen, contact-groups

My Family Contact Group is still intact but the menus have changed and I can't seem to find a way to move it back to a Home Screen or even change it with the Favorites Group which is on the Home Screen and I don't need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and just figured out how to fix it.

- Go to the screen on which you want to display your family contacts group.
- Press the screen until the 'Drag to rearrange, edit, or remove' message appears at the top of the screen.
- Drag the screen to the 'Edit' icon at the top left of the screen.

You will get options to 'Select a group for widget' or 'Edit group.'

If you choose 'Select a group for widget,' it will pull up your list of contact groups.

Choose the one you wish to display.